# What query does DESCRIBE run behind the scenes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a query that `DESCRIBE` runs behind the scenes?

For example:

- `DESCRIBE myTable`
- `DESCRIBE myView`

Is there something I can run against the `informational_schema` to run that query, or it's internal-only?

Comment: It's basically joining `information_schema.columns` and `information_schema.key_column_usage`.

Comment: @Barmar oh I see, so it basically treats a view as a pseudo-table in `columns` and stores the column types and all, right?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at `select * from columns where table_name = 'some_view'`

Comment: The `key_column_usage` table is just used for the `Key` column of `describe`.

Comment: @Barmar -- thanks so much. is that standardized ansi, or unique to mysql's implementation of information_schema? In other words, would the above work on Postgres, Oracle, MsSQL, etc. as-is or it's a bit different for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `DESCRIBE` is standard SQL. It is provided in MySQL for compatibility with Oracle statement of the same name. There's a comment to that effect here: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L13974-L13980

> ```
> /* A Oracle compatible synonym for show */
> describe_stmt:
>           describe_command table_ident opt_describe_column
> ```

Both `SHOW COLUMNS` and `DESCRIBE <table>` end up calling the same function, `build_show_columns_query()`, implemented here:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/dd/info_schema/show.cc#L612-L617

It's basically a query against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, with a `WHERE` clause to select for one specific schema and table, and optionally other user-defined conditions. You could write the same query yourself.

Other implementations of SQL have different commands to give similar metadata:

- PostgreSQL uses the `\d <table>` client command: https://www.educba.com/postgresql-describe-table/
- Microsoft SQL Server uses `exec sp_columns <table>`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
- SQLite uses `pragma table_info(<table>)`: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-describe-table/
- Informix uses `info columns for <table>`: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statements-info-statement

If you want to know the equivalent for any other brands, probably you can do a google search for "describe table in <brand>".

Comment: thanks again for the answer. On a sort of unrelated note, from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/dd/info_schema/show.cc#L612-L617, is mysql mostly just pure C? Or does it have a lot of actual C++

Comment: It seems a mix, I guess just depends on when it was incorporated into the project and what it's doing, for example: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/locks/shared_spin_lock.cc

Comment: Yes, it's developed on 25+ years of code design, so it's imperfect C++. It didn't even support `cmake` until about 2010, if I recall. I have read reports that the developers hate the codebase because it's so badly organized, but to refactor it without causing instability in the product will take decades.

Comment: I assumed it needed to join with `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`, but apparently that information is cached in `COLUMNS.COLUMN_KEY`.